# How do I print this star pattern in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I need to print a star pattern like this:

```
*****
**  *
*** *
*****
```

The code that I have tried is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=1;i<5;i++){
        for(j=1;j<5;j++){
            if(i==1 || j==4 || i==4  )
             // if(j==4 || i==4)
            cout<<"*";
            if(i>1 && i<4){
                for(k=1;k<3;k++){
                    cout<<"";
                }
            }
            else {
                cout<<"";
            }

        }
        cout<<endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
****                                                                                                                          
*                                                                                                                             
*                                                                                                                             
****
```

So, you see I'm having trouble printing the star at the end of each line. and as you can see in the desired output I provided above, in the 2nd and 3rd line, I need to print them with gaps. Now, as I've given the code, I tried to do that but not sure why isn't it working. So, I need your help in achieving this output.

Many other questions have similar title but this is about a completely different star pattern.

P.S: On a side note, I want to mention that I've been learning C++ for over a year now, and I am still having trouble with loops. I have understood other things such as functions, if-else, structures, arrays, basic oop etc, but for some reason, loops trouble me so I thought I should do these star pattern exercises. If you guys have any suggestions how I can improve my logic in loops (especially the nested ones), then it would be very helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `cout << "";` does **absolutely nothing.** Did you mean `cout << " ";` (note the space character)?

Comment: @scohe001 oh. Yes, you are right. I meant to use space

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius  Thanks. But, do you have any source on how to learn loops and their logics. I mean whenever I search on google, every page just shows its syntax.

Comment: I highly recommend learning an easier, more modern and more useful language like python.  I've been a senior C++ coder for 10+ years and python is so much easier to use and learn with. C++ should be used only when absolutely necessary

Comment: `std::cout << "*****\n
**  *\n
*** *\n
*****\n";` - done.

Comment: @Zain763 "_But, do you have any source on how to learn loops and their logics._" I already linked you to a list of C++ books, that is reviewed by SO community.. What else do you need?

Comment: @AviadRozenhek 1) That is, frankly, opinion based. I, in my professional career worked with C++, and C#, but I still prefer C++. Python is mostly used for build scripts in our environment, rather than actual development, and even after sometimes touching Python: I still prefer C++. 2) "_I highly recommend learning an easier, more modern and more useful language_" What's not modern about C++? There are feature additions to the language every 3 years, since 2011, which help in modernizing the language.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius it's just that I don't see books covering loops that much.

Comment: @Zain how many (and which) C++ books have you read? Loops should be covered extensively in any beginner book worth its salt, as they're at the core of any programming language.

Comment: @Zain763 "_it's just that I don't see books covering loops that much._" There are plenty of bad books. That's why there's a peer reviewed list, of the books, that are deemed "good", on SO, that I linked you to.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius look i love c++ I spent my career on it, but compare the answers in this thread written in C++ - which take 15+ lines with my answer which takes 6 lines, and you'll see why python is superior **for learning**

Comment: oh okay. I will try reading some from the list. Currently, I have only studied "Object oriented programming in C++ by Robert Lafore"

Comment: @AviadRozenhek Maybe.. Since algorithms, and loops, as a concept, are language-agnostic, one could learn the algorithmic thinking, before tackling the advanced language features.. That makes sense. But, since I my path of learning programming was: Pascal -> C -> C++ | Assembly (both in parallel) -> Java, I, personally, don't see a difficulty in this learning curve.. While I can understand while it can be discouraging to others..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code with my comments:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 5; // columns count
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)  // i is row index
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)  // j is current symbol index in line i
        { // note, you print 5 symbols per line, so j <= 5, not j < 5
            if (i > 1 && i < n && j != n && j > i)  // for lines 2 and 3 indexes [3-4] and [4] print space, print * for symbol #5 (last symbol in a line is always *)
            {
                 cout << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                 cout << "*";
            }
         }

         cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why in the if condition, we are doing j != n

Comment: if `j == n` than it means current symbol is the last symbol in line. last symbol is `*` always so that's why this condition added

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it. Could you explain please?

Comment: For example you have line `**   *` (line #2 from your example). If index starts from 1, last index of element in line is 5 (= n, columns count). Note that in this line all symbols after symbol #2 are spaces, expect last one. That's why `j > i` is needed (all symbols on positions to the right of diagonal are spaces). But last symbol is always `*`, so there is condition to check if current index is index of last symbol in line (`j != n`) and if it is then it prints star instead of space

Comment: this solution is hard to read and understand. readability counts, as code is read more times than it is written.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks a lot, man. Now, by reading what you wrote carefully, I have understood the code. So, thanks a lot for helping me out. Now, why are we checking j>i can you explain that? I'm sorry I've understood eveything except that. So, if you could help me with this, I can understand the program. Again, thank you so much for taking so much of your time and helping me out.

Comment: Look at  your star pattern (except first and last line): line #2 starts with 2 stars, line 3 starts from 3 starts and so on. On each line you should print i starts (where i is line number) and after it you should start printing spaces. `j > i` means that you reached diagonal and should start printing spaces (j is current symbol number, i is line number)

Answer (score 0):

```
 i=1;i<5;
```

This runs 4 times. i=1,i=2,i=3,i=4.

You either need `i<6` or `i<=5`

Comment: "_You either need `i<6` or `i<=5`_" Or, alternatively, start at `i=0`.

Comment: True. If that is the way you go, you need to change the if statements and which indices you check for

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to make the "shortest, cleanest C++ code," you could do it all in a single loop:

```
int n = 10; //input

std::cout << std::string(n, '*') << std::endl; //First line
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    std::cout << std::string(i, '*');
              << std::string(n - i - 1, ' ') 
              << '*' << std::endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

here's a solution in python. you should be able to extrapolate from that into C++

```py
N = 10
print('*' * N)
for row in range(2, N+1):
    print('*' * row, end='')
    print(' ' * (N-row -1), end='')
    print('*')
```

here's a solution in C++, which does the exact same thing but is longer than the python solution. I gave the python solution first because I believed it shows the thought process more cleanly than the C++ counterpart.

```
int N = 10;
for(int i=0 ; i<N ; ++i)
  cout << '*';
cout << endl;
for (int row = 2; row < N; ++row) {
  for(int i=0 ; i<row ; ++i)
     cout << "*";
  for(int i=row ; i<N-1; ++i)
     cout << ' ';
  cout << '*' << endl;
}
```

this is the output for N=10

```
**********
**       *
***      *
****     *
*****    *
******   *
*******  *
******** *
**********
```

Comment: Please don't answer C++ questions with python or other unrelated languages.

Comment: @machine_1 well its not really a c++ question is it? its a simple __learn to program__ question. actually writing the answer in python illustrates the principles better IMHO than in cumbersome C++.

Comment: What @machine_1 says is spot on. If two languages share some common syntax it may be tempting to just copy/paste - but that's very often not the correct answer for the target language. In this case, you've demonstrated an algorithm, but the usedd syntax is so different from C++'s that OP would have to learn python to make sense of it and translate it into C++. Not helpful. And, yes, it's a C++ question.

Comment: it is my opinion that regardless of how useful C++ may be, it is not a good language to learn programming in.

@TedLyngmo I've been answering n00b questions for fun this entire evening, and it just hurts my eyes to see people who struggle with loops also needing to handle c++ syntax at the same time. 

I've given an answer which IMHO is easier to read, and suggested that the student will be better served learning a different python as a first language instead.

if this helps even 1 person learn programming more quickly, than it definitely was worth losing reputation points on this answer

Comment: So, your opinion is one thing. I happen to disagree. But answering a question tagged with a specific language with a different language isn't helping anyone.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood something about SO in general. It's a Q&A and the tags helps people with questions to get answers. Your answer may help one person who stumbles along searching for an answer for a C++ question, but also knows python - but that's just by pure chance. The code you've shown does not show an ounce of effort really. Why not `C++`-ify it before posting it as an answer? **I** know how to translate your algorithm into C++ line-by-line. It does not translate well, but it's doable. If you do not like C++, don't use this forum as some means to get people over to python.

Comment: thanks all, i've added a c++ solution which is shorter and simpler than the other solutions and is translated 1-to-1 from the python solution I showed. lets make the world a better place

Comment: @AviadRozenhek Much better - and it goes to show, translating 1-to-1 is rarely a good idea. :-) Cheers!

Comment: @TedLyngmo, how do you mean? this solution is superior to the others, in terms of readability and cleanliness

Comment: @Aviad I think with the right knowledge of C++, you can make something just as beautiful as your Python solution. In fact, I attempted just that above. Just because it's not Python, doesn't mean it can't be short and sweet :p

Comment: @scohe001 fantastic, I'm happy my python code was inspiration

Comment: @AviadRozenhek I think you misunderstood my comment. My -1 is a +1 now  - I still think the python part at the beginning of the answer is just noise though.

Answer (score -1):

The Issue is that "" does not register a space, " " will though.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 3)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else if (i == 1) {
                if (j == 2 || j == 3) {
                    cout << " ";
                }
                else {
                    cout << "*"; 
                }
            }
            else if (i == 2) {
                if (j == 3) {
                    cout << " ";
                }
                else {
                    cout << "*";
                }
            }

        }
        cout << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: would be nice to have a solution that works for any number of lines. in this case n=5 but what if n=10?